# Angular 4 --prod removes spaces in meta tags and messing up views

Tags: javascript, html, angular

OK, this might be a weird one, I'll use one tag as an example.

What it should look like.

`<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />`

Notice spaces between `...scalable=no, width=d...`. Everything is ok, when running `ng serve` or `ng build`, but then `ng build --prod` turns the above into :

`<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no,width=device-width" />`

And somehow the browser can't scale for mobile.

How do I preserve this? I suspect something else will also break somewhere 'cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the **[specification of this meta tag](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-device-adapt/#viewport-meta)** :

> The recognized separator between property/value pairs is comma for the Safari implementation. Some implementations have supported both commas and semicolons. Because of that, existing content use semicolons instead of commas. Authors should be using comma in order to ensure content works as expected in all UAs, but implementors may add support for both to ensure interoperability for existing content.

Are you sure you don't have another issue ?

Comment: Well, it might be another issue too, but I'm only noticing the missing spaces over there between `dev` and `prod` builds.

Comment: Are you running both envs on the same device ?

Comment: I'm running both on different devices, mac, emulator, and a physical device. Fails on Mobile.

Comment: How does it fail ? What is the issue you're facing exactly ?